# Catching a failure in IPython image display

Tags: python, web-services, exception, jupyter-notebook, ipython

In my Jupyter Notebook, I need to delegate the rendering of a Graphviz source file to an external service, for instance [QuickChart](https://quickchart.io/documentation/graphviz-api/):

```py
from IPython.display import Image
url = "https://quickchart.io/graphviz?graph=graph{a--b}"
Image(url=url)
```

However, if this fails (e.g., the server is down, or the rate limit is reached, etc.), I would like to be able to fall back to another service. The screenshot below shows the result of a working example and a failure case:

[image]

How could I catch the error which produces this broken image icon? I would be interested in a general answer, independent from a particular service or image format. Reading the [source code](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/main/IPython/core/display.py) gave me no clue, and the `__dict__` object only contains the parameters:

```py
>>> Image(url=url).__dict__
{'format': 'https://quikchat.io/graphviz?graph=graph{a--b}',
 'embed': False,
 'width': None,
 'height': None,
 'retina': False,
 'unconfined': False,
 'alt': None,
 'url': 'https://quikchat.io/graphviz?graph=graph{a--b}',
 'filename': None,
 'data': None,
 'metadata': {}}
```

Answer (score 1):

This url supports the `HEAD` call, so you could use that to check the url:

```py
import requests

r = requests.head('https://quickchart.io/graphviz?graph=graph{a--b}')

# all good
r.raise_for_status()

r = requests.head('https://quickchat.io/graphviz?graph=graph{a--b}')

# fails
r.raise_for_status()
```

Where the `HEAD` call doesn't return data

Comment: Thanks a lot for this LBYL solution, but I would prefer to detect the failure from the returned IPython object.

Comment: I think LBYL is the optimal solution. `Image` takes both `file` and `data` kwargs. You could swap to using `requests` to obtain the raw data and check the actual data, then pass that to `Image(data=data)`. Checking the rendered object is unnecessary and probably far more difficult